# Widget for webmasters in JavaScript and ID-collision

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a widget that could be placed in another websites/forums.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/x.js" />
<div id="myid"></div>
```

But there is a problem - when someone put on one website two or more such widgets they will not work correctly because of the ID.

What can I do to prevent such situation?

I can't use class because I need to have access to this div from JS.
I thought about adding a random-generated number to the end of ID, but there will be still possibility of ID-collision (small, but there will be).

Comment: Well, you don't want your users to paste multiple SCRIPT elements when they want multiple widgets. The SCRIPT elements should exist only once because there is only one JavaScript file. So, what you want to do is have some mechanism for multiple widgets. For instance, the user pastes the SCRIPT element only once (preferably at the bottom of the page), and then, for every widget instance on the page, he pastes a DIV element. You **can** use classes for this. Your script then gets the DIV's by class-name, and then executes the code for each such DIV.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to be more flexible. So, instead of having a defined html id and force the user to have it, you should provide a way to let user choose its id. And so, a call must be done.

Something like this is cleaner :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/x.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    X.callMethod("myId");
</script>
<div id="myid"></div>
```

This method has two advantages :

- it lets **user define its own id**
- the user specifies what behavior he wants from your script. With, that, you could add other methods which can be used in same way : **user doesn't have the feeling that your code is intrusive**, it's him who decides if he wants a feature or not.

Comment: Great point, but *modular* is the wrong term for this - you probably meant *flexible* or *adaptable*.

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the script... which at processing time generates a div and assigns it a unique ID.  (Within that logic, you could check for duplicates)

Presuming you don't expect your widget to be included 1,000's of times... something like this (untested) should work.

```
var uniqueID;
var foundUniqueID = false;
var idx = 0;
while(foundUniqueID != true){
  uniqueID = 'myID_' + idx;
  if(document.getElementById(uniqueID)){
    idx++;
  } else {
    foundUniqueID = true;
  }
}
//create your DIV with your uniqueID etc.
```